# In C++11, is it possible to wrap a template function in a std::function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function, stdbind

If i have a template function in C++11, is it then possible to wrap it in a `std::function`?

My problem is like this:

I have a generic function (say a sum function) where the return type depends on the types of the arguments:

```
template <typename T>
auto sum(T const& a, T const& b) -> decltype(a+b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

and I want to wrap it in a `std:function` for specific argument types (say int). I'm trying the following:

```
int main()
{
  std::function<int(int,int)> intsum = std::bind(static_cast<int(*)(int,int)>(&sum), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
  auto mysum = intsum(2, 4);

  std::cout << mysum << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But compiling the above code produces an error:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to type ‘int (*)(int, int)
```

Is there some way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried `sum<int>`?

Comment: _template function_ is not a function. If you use the correct name _function template_ it makes it clear that you are not dealing with a function yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't wrap a generic function in a *specific instance of* `std::function`, which is what you asked for.

You can, however, wrap a fully-specified *instance* of a generic function, which is what your code is actually trying to do:

```
template <typename T>
auto sum(T const& a, T const& b) -> decltype(a+b)
{
  return a + b;
}

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::function<int(int,int)> intsum =
    std::bind(sum<int>,
              std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
  auto mysum = intsum(2, 4);

  std::cout << mysum << std::endl;
}
```

Or more simply

```
  std::function<int(int,int)> intsum = sum<int>;
```

Or of course if you don't really need to *wrap* it, just:

```
  auto mysum = sum(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just specialize the template and use that:

```
std::function<int(int,int)> intsum = sum<int>;
auto mysum = intsum(2, 4);

std::cout << mysum << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you got the type wrong.

There is no `int(int,int)` overload of `sum<?>`.  So when you `static_cast<int(*)(int,int)(sum)`, it complains that it cannot do the conversion.

There is a `int(int const&,int const&)` overload.  If you `static_cast<int(*)(int const&, int const&)>(sum)` it would work.

Conversion of a function template to a pointer to function won't work if there is no such overload to point to.

There are three approaches that are reasonable.

First, cast to the right type.  `static_cast<int(*)(int const&,int const&)>(sum)`.

Second, explicitly specialize.  `sum<int>` instead of the `static_cast` expression.

Third, create an overload set object:

```
struct sum_t{
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const
  -> decltype(sum(std::declval<Args>()...))
  {
    return sum(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
static sum_t sum_os;
```

and replace `static_cast<int(*)(int,int)>(sum)` with `sum_os`.

`sum_os` can be passed to `bind` or `std::function` or whatever, and the overload resolution is deferred until the invocation code.

As a bonus, it is easier for the compiler to optimize than a function pointer call.

As a negative, perfect forwarding is imperfect.

A C++14 version of the overload set is:

```
[](auto&&...args)->
decltype(sum(decltype(args)(args)...))
{ return sum(decltype(args)(args)...); }
```

which can be turned into a macro:

```
#define OVERLOAD_SET(FUNC) \
  [](auto&&...args)-> \
  decltype(FUNC(decltype(args)(args)...)) \
  { return FUNC(decltype(args)(args)...); }
```

which lets you simply do `OVERLOAD_SET(sum)` at the point of use, and pass in the entire overload set.

Comment: why not `->decltype(auto)` in the C++14 lambda version?

Comment: @piotrs. SFINAE does not work with return type deduction.  I want to be able to ask if a call is a valid one.

Comment: ah, but how can you benefit from SFINAE with a single lambda expression? I mean, there can't be any fallback, can be?

Comment: @piotrs. The consumer can ask if a given expression is a valid call, and have their own fallbacks.  As an example, if someone fixed `std::function`'s ctor (bad std bad library) to only accept things you can actualky invoke with the signature, a pair of overloads `std::function<void()>` and `std::function<bool()>` could be dispatched between.